# Cannot get Discord.js to embed THEN delete

Tags: javascript, embed, discord, discord.js, wrapper

EDIT: Trying to make it more clear. I want the embed listed below in the part where it says EMBED GOES HERE.

Unsure if i can even do that. My structure is calling externally for files named in example: test.js through swap args. Creating a very rough command handler.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'test',
    description: "Embed",
    execute(message, args){
        message.delete();
message.channel.send(`**EMBED GOES HERE**`).then(async sentMessage => {
    await sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 10000 });
});
    }
}
```

Where this is the embed.

```
 "embed": {
              "title": "Test",
              "thumbnail": 'google.com',
              "url": "google.com",
              "description": 'test',
              "color": 16763981,
              "footer": {
              }
```

Comment: fyi: Java != JavaScript

Comment: Sorry i type java i thought, i guess it autofilled.

Comment: Yes, you typed Java. But this is JavaScript. Knowing which language you're working with usually helps fix issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An embed is a specially formatted JSON object, which can be easily assigned to any variable.  However, the data portion of channel.send is also an object, so in the end it will be an object nested in an object.  (The second one, I will create inline)  This may be a bit confusing, because an embed is an option, not part of the content.

```
let myEmbed = {
    title: "Test",
    thumbnail: { url: 'google.com'},
    url: "google.com",
    description: 'test',
    color: 16763981,
    footer: { }
};

message.channel.send({embed: myEmbed }).then(async sentMessage => {
    await sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 10000 });
    message.delete();
});
```

Comment: Aweseom! That is pretty much exactly what i was looking for. Is there any reason i am having such difficulting taking advice from others? Is it because of the unintentional nesting and file structure? I have been having an impossible time with simple stuff like !kick and all that because my commands all have to get passed through the args. But am unsure how i need to be formatting in the js files outside of index.

Comment: Well, as was the case with this one, interpretation of what you are attempting to do might be the problem.  Try to be as clear and succinct as possible.  Give the problem, give what it's doing now, give what you expect it to do, and give the reprex.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example